# Awk syntax error due to improper placement of the function definition

Tags: awk

It is embarrassing, but could someone briefly explain why this gives syntax error?

```
echo why this fails? | gawk '{

function why(fail) {
        print fail
    }

why($0)

}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function definition has to be at the top level. You have it inside the `{`...`}`.

```
echo This works | gawk ' 
function why(fail) { 
    print fail 
} 
 
{ 
    why($0) 
}'
```